# Whenever I visit any website, then the image on webpage will be animate (With all the effects of the image like pan zoom, left right slide)

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, webkit

Whenever I visit any website, then the image that is on that page will be animate (With all the effects of the image like pan zoom, left right slide) automatically OR when mouse hover to activate animation,

I have image effect code.
how will it happen. Help me please.

Comment: Are you saying you're experiencing this on every website you visit and want it to go away, or you want this to happen on every website you visit?

Comment: Yes. on every website

Comment: What I mean is, you're already seeing this happen, or you *want* this to happen?

Comment: I want this to happen? I am looking for this for the first time in my problem.

Comment: If you want something like this to happen, you'll need to write a browser extension. That extension can be given access to any website and manipulate its DOM and run scripts etc. In the extension, select the current website's image and then run your effect code.

Comment: Dear sir ji, I use Google Chrome browser and want to run this type of code in chrome browser. so that whenever I visit a website, the images of that website start to be automatically animated or the mouse hover will start to be animated

Comment: Right. That's what the Chrome extension will be able to do for you, if you write it accordingly.